# Python 2.7 Get Command stdout/stderr

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the subprocess module in Python 2.7. My code looks like

```
cmd = 'unrar l -p%s %s' % (pwd, filename)
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = proc.communicate()
```

This code works fine on Windows 7/10, but it does not work on Ubuntu 16.04. I debugged and saw the variable err is empty, which on Windows contains the error message. And the variable output contains the command's help message. It looks like the command was run without any options.

If this is not the correct way to run a command and get its stdout/stderr output, what is the correct way?

Comment: it will fail if `pwd` or `filename` contain spaces. Consider `shlex.split()` or just `cmd = ["unrar","l","-p",pwd,filename]`, and drop `shell=True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the tip provided by Jean-François Fabre, I dropped the `shell=True` parameter and the program works fine. I guess I will need to read the documentation on `subprocess.Popen()` to figure out why on Windows I need `shell=True` while on Ubuntu I don't, but for now I am happy.